# How to run a function only when two events from two different elements have fired?

Tags: javascript, synchronization, html5-video, html5-audio

I have two media elements:

```
<audio id="aud"></audio>
<video id="vid"></video>
```

I've attached media urls to both of them.

Then I load and play them by doing `audio.load()` and `video.load()` followed by `audio.play()` and `video.play()` in listener

```
audio.load();
video.load();
video.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
    video.play();     
});
audio.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
    audio.play();     
});
```

Both start loading, audio loads first and it takes around 1-2 seconds to video to load.

When they actually start playing depends on when "**canplay**" event is fired by each media elements. (which is fired after loading is done for at-least a couple of frames)

what I wanna do is, call `audio.play()` AND `video.play()` together ONLY when "`canplay`" event is fired for **both** of them. How can I achieve this?

*note that I DO need to use both audio and video element, and i'm trying to achieve a close but not perfect synchronisation at start.*

in brief: what i want to achieve is:

```
audio.load();
video.load();

// when video can "canplay" and when audio can "canplay" ONLY then

video.play();   
audio.play();
```

Comment: Don't load them one after another.  Start audio.load();  then trigger video.load() when audio is loaded. the trigger play for both after Video is loaded. : audio.load(); audio.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
    video.load();
});

video.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
    audio.play();     video.play();     
});

Comment: When you wish to wait for many asynchronous actions to complete, you use `Promise.all`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @AntiqTech your answer seems to be way smaller than others, is there a possible downside of it? or it's just for MY use case that seems to fit ferfectly?

Comment: I just rearranged your code. Only downside that I can think of is that "audio.load();" might throw an exception or that "canplay" event never gets fired for some reason, thus breaking the flow. I can add this as  an answer if you want to vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global flags:

```js
let audCanPlay=false;
let vidCanPlay=false;

function audPlay() {
  audCanPlay=true;
  console.log("audCanPlay=true");
  if(vidCanPlay) playBoth();
}

function vidPlay() {
  vidCanPlay=true;
  console.log("vidCanPlay=true");
  if(audCanPlay) playBoth();
}

function playBoth() {
  console.log("audio.play();");
  console.log("video.play();");
}

/* commented for demonstration
audio.addEventListener("canplay", audPlay);
video.addEventListener("canplay", vidPlay);
audio.load();
video.load();
*/
```

```html
<audio id="aud"></audio>
<button id="audBtn" onclick="audPlay()">Mimic Audio canplay</button>
<video id="vid"></video>
<button id="vidBtn" onclick="vidPlay()">Mimic Video canplay</button>
```

I think it's better to add the event listeners before calling the load methods.
I think it's better to do it this way, rather than waiting for one to finish/canplay and only then call the second = saves time/faster.

Comment: event listeners are better before the load asin? aslo should't we clear listener once function runs, I'll be calling the okay method many times during the playback..

Comment: I don't know how the audio and video work.
probably: `let audio=document.getElementById("aud")` and similar for video,
then: `addEventListener`s,
then: `load`.

Comment: What is "the okay method"?

Comment: In function `playBoth` you can add at the end:
`audCanPlay=false; vidCanPlay=false;`, and:
`audio.removeEventListener("canplay", audPlay); video.removeEventListener("canplay", vidPlay);`,
but, you'll have to add the listeners again whenever you change the sources.
I don't know if `canplay` fires more than once per source - if it doesn't = I don't see why to remove the listeners - just clear the flags (set to `false`).

Comment: See [canplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) (and [canplaythrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event)).
And [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement).

Comment: @shriyanskapoor, thank you for accepting my answer!
Will you up-vote it too?

Answer (score 0):

Promises resolved by `canplay` events and combined with `Promise.all` to wait for multiple events come to mind.

However, how complex it needs to be also depends on how general purpose it is to be.  For the simple case of waiting for exactly *one* video and *one* audio to be ready to play, I would only use the one promise and count events as they arrive.

Note that to catch events on elements that retrieve files it is unsafe to set `src` or `href` attributes before adding event listeners.

Concept code (untested) to add listeners, set sources and return a promise when both are ready:

```
const loadAV = (video, vidSrc, audio, audioSrc, timeout) {
    let resolve, reject;
    const p = new Promise( (r,j) => { resolve = r, reject = j};
    let count = 0;
    let timer;

    const listenCanPlay = () => {
        if( ++count == 2) {
            resolve();
            unListen();
        }
    };
    const unListen = () => {
        video.removeEventListener("canplay", listenCanPlay);
        audio.removeEventListener("canplay", listenCanPlay);
        if( timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    };

    if( timeout) {
        timer = setTimeout( ()=> {
            if( count < 2) {
                unListen();
                reject( new Error(`loadAV timed out after ${timeout} msec`)
            }
        }, timeout);
    }
    video.addEventListener("canplay", listenCanPlay);
    audio.addEventListener("canplay", listenCanPlay);
    video.src = vidSrc;
    audio.src = audioSrc;
    return p;
}
```

which would then be called like

```
 loadAV( video, video_url, audio, audio_url, 15000)
 .then(()=>{ video.play(); audio.play()})
 .catch(err=> console.log(err));
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the wonderful answer, though could you please check the comment on my question by AntiqTech ? What's the downside of using that, it seems pretty small for the job..

Comment: @shriyanskapoor keeping it simple is good. If loading resources sequentially is  acceptable in terms of performance, then loading loading them that way would take less code. Handling error conditions should be included, and allowing another video and sound track to played after the first pair finishes would start to complicate matters again. All the best with your endeavors.